# Why is it wrong to instantiate an object to null before instantiation?

Tags: c#, object

I have a situation as below:

Some class

```
public class Numbers
{
}
```

Some other class

```
public class Calculations
{
  Numbers objNumber = null;

  public void abc()
  {
    objNumbers = new Numbers();
  }
}
```

What is wrong with the statement `Numbers objNumber = null;`?
I know I could have simply ignored the `null` assignment; just curious why this is wrong.

Comment: What is your idea about _wrong_  in this case? Is your program error because of this null assignment?

Comment: There are no errors, I just need to the concept behind not initializing an Object type to Null. To put it in other words, What is the difference between Number obj = new Numbers(); and my case.

Answer (score 8):

It's not wrong, it's just unnecessary, all reference types are null by default, so there is no point on initializing the variable to null because the type of the variable is a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

Reference types in c#, when declared are initialized automatically with null value. So there is no difference in

```
Numbers objNumbers = null;
```

and

```
Numbers objNumbers;
```

Both will work the same. You can check this behavior by using a debugging the code.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, Will it impact the performance of the application in anyway ?

Comment: @mukulsharma1146, Not at all. One is implicitly done by compiler and in one case you are telling the compiler explicitly. So there will be no performace impact anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with what you are doing, just additional note types are created with `default` value. It won't make any difference assigning null or ignoring it.

I see just there is a typo, which you could easily identify and fix it.

There is an extra `s` in `objNumbers`, the field is defined as `objNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

The `null` will be the default value for the `object`(reference type). So It will be null even without the assignment by you. And there is nothing wrong with that statement.

In short

`Numbers objNumbers = null;` and `Numbers objNumbers;` are same.

Consider the following example;

```
Numbers objNumbers = new Numbers();
objNumbers = null;
```

Here assignment of `null` make Sense

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it is not wrong, as the code compiles (provided you add an s to your field name).

However, there are multiple reasons this code might be unreliable from a perspective of design or correctness.

You code has a mutable field not initialized to any meaningful value: Consider the possibility that the method `abc()` may not get called prior to the value stored at `objNumbers` being accessed, which will result in a null reference exception for any likely use case.

Now consider following the [null object pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178399/how-do-i-create-a-null-object-in-c-sharp) and initializing the field to an instance of this null version of the `Numbers` class.

That code would be much less likely to produce a null reference exception... and it would force you to think about your application's behavior in the case where accessing the field occurs prior to the execution of method `abc`.

For both these reasons, in my opinion, it is a favorable design discipline to avoid initializing your fields/properties to null.

Additional reading on the topic, such as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717957/null-object-pattern), shows dealing with nulls is often considered a problem in need of a solution.  Initializing your code with instances and values instead of null is a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think much. Even though you don't assign still all objects before allocating memory are null.